# I'm getting an occasional "flash" of a previous page when navigating in Durandal

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

When the app has been inactive for a while and I click on a navigation link, I see my "page isnavigating" spinner rotating for a few seconds and then just before the new page loads, the old page I navigated away from flashes on screen for a split second and it's highly distracting.

My content section in my shell.html page is:

```
    <section>
        <!--<section id="content" class="main"> -->
        <!--ko router: { transition:'entrance', cacheViews:true }--><!--/ko-->
        <!--</section>-->
    </section>
```

It happens whether cacheviews is set to true or false, so it's not that. It also happens whether transitions are turned on or not.

Once the app is loaded and actively being used, it is responsive, fast and the transitions work perfectly.

Comment: We would need to see a little more code than what you're showing.  Could you post the views (HTML) and viewModels (JS) of two of your compositions--the *from* and *to*, so to speak.

Comment: I will return to this, sorry. I have a few other pressing issues with the app that require more attention right now.

Comment: It could possibly be browser-related. Have you tested it in other browsers?

Comment: I thought that too Brett but I just tested it in firefox as well as chrome and it does exactly the same thing. I tried stepping through on debug and it's really odd. It may be related to a "session management" module I'm interacting with (setting an "isbusy" observable) and I'm just working through that now.

Comment: Yup. Definitely related to that session flag.  I have a "session.js" module that returns a "isBusy" knockout observable and I set/unset this at various stages in the code. In my "activate" method on the page, I set this to "isBusy" whilst data is being fetched and at that exact moment, the old page vanishes. As soon as I set it back to not "isBusy" when data returns, the old page reappears for a fraction of a second, then the new one does.  If I remove the "isBusy" set/unset, the flash does not happen!

Comment: Glad you figured out the problem! You should copy your comments into an answer for this question to close it out.

Comment: I will do when/if I have a better idea of why just updating a knockout observable should make the screen disappear/reappear!